# Android and Google fusion tables

Tags: android, dictionary, google-fusion-tables

I want to build a map view with a google fusion table layer, bringing data from a public table. I'm searching for tutorials, infos ... Someone can give me some advises about how I can proceed? Thanks :)

Comment: hello, I am doing the same. Which approch you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed might be to use the App inventor Fusion Tables Control. It's quite simple and lightweight.

http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/notready.html#FusiontablesControl

Otherwise here is a simple example app in Java

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Fusion_Tables_API

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

here is my android app that uses fusion tables to sync it's data:

https://jedld@github.com/jedld/GiNote.git

The part where it also lets the user choose the google account to use and the retrieval of an auth token might also interest you.